# How to plot multiple points. Windowforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, plot

Windows form. My code repaints a point every time I press a button. For example, if I put 1,1,1 in x,y and z text box. It will show at first. Then, I put 2,2,2 in the text boxes and press a button. the first point(1,1,1) disappears and only (2,2,2) shows. I want to show multiple points(like if I press button twice, two points would show in the plot) and store all the points in a form of array if possible. Is there anyway to proceed this?

```
   Public Property PointCoordinates() As Vector3
    Get
        Dim x As Single = 0, y As Single = 0, z As Single = 0
        Single.TryParse(xcor.Text, x)
        Single.TryParse(ycor.Text, y)
        Single.TryParse(zcor.Text, z)

        Return New Vector3(x, y, z)
    End Get
    Set(value As Vector3)
        xcor.Text = value.X.ToString()
        ycor.Text = value.Y.ToString()
        zcor.Text = value.Z.ToString()
    End Set
End Property


   Public Sub GlControl1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles GlControl1.Paint
    'First Clear Buffers

    GlControl1.MakeCurrent()
    GL.ClearColor(GlControl1.BackColor)
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit Or ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit)

    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview)
    GL.LoadIdentity()



    'Basic Setup for viewing
    Dim perspective As Matrix4 = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(1.04, 4 / 3, 1, 10000) 'Setup Perspective
    Dim lookat As Matrix4 = Matrix4.LookAt(100, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0) 'Setup camera
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection) 'Load Perspective
    GL.LoadIdentity()
    GL.LoadMatrix(perspective)
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview) 'Load Camera
    GL.LoadIdentity()
    GL.LoadMatrix(lookat)
    GL.Viewport(0, 0, GlControl1.Width, GlControl1.Height) 'Size of window
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest) 'Enable correct Z Drawings
    GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Less) 'Enable correct Z Drawings

    'Rotating

    'Draw pyramid, Y is up, Z is twards you, X is left and right
    'Vertex goes (X,Y,Z)
    GL.LineWidth(1.5F)
    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Lines)
    'Face 1
    GL.Color3(Color.Red)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0)
    GL.Vertex3(25, 0, 0)
    GL.Vertex3(21.5, 1.25, -1.25)
    GL.Vertex3(25, 0, 0)
    GL.Vertex3(21.5, -1.25, 1.25)
    GL.Vertex3(25, 0, 0)

    GL.Color3(Color.Green)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 25, 0)
    GL.Vertex3(-1.25, 21.5, 1.25)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 25, 0)
    GL.Vertex3(1.25, 21.5, -1.25)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 25, 0)

    GL.Color3(Color.Blue)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 25)
    GL.Vertex3(-1.25, 1.25, 21.5)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 25)
    GL.Vertex3(1.25, -1.25, 21.5)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 25)

    'Finish the begin mode with "end"
    GL.End()



        'Draw single point on the origin
    GL.PointSize(2.0F)
    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Points)
    GL.Color3(Color.Black)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0)
    GL.End()

    Dim vector = PointCoordinates

    GL.PointSize(5.0F)
    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Points)
    GL.Color3(Color.Black)
    GL.Vertex3(vector)
    GL.End()

    GraphicsContext.CurrentContext.VSync = True 'Caps frame rate as to not over run GPU
    GlControl1.SwapBuffers() 'Takes from the 'GL' and puts into control

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

            GlControl1.Refresh()
End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `List(Of Vector3)` and each time you want a new point, create a `Vector3` and `Add` it to the list.  In your `Paint` event handler, loop through that list and draw each point.

Comment: I created the list but how can I add vector3 to a list?

Comment: By calling the `Add` method of the list, which is why I wrote `Add` rather than add in the original answer.

Comment: Dim List1 As New List(Of Vector3)
List1.Add(Pointcoordinate)

   GL.PointSize(5.0F)
        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Points)
        GL.Color3(Color.Black)
        GL.Vertex3(List1)
        GL.End()

but error said public share vertex3 couldnt be converted to open tk.

Comment: If you were cooking from a recipe and it said to add an egg, would you expect it to be OK to use an egg carton instead?  If `GL.Vertex3` expects a `Vector3` then you can't pass it a `List(Of Vector3)`.